# Javascript storing actual name of a string variable rather than its value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, storage

I want to generate a new string variable everyday and store it into the local storage as a new entry. The format of the string is "timeDataXXXX" where XXXX is a number showing number of days since midnight January 1 1970. XXXX is calculated and returned by a function `numDaysSinceUTC();`

Here is what I try to do

```
var newStorageName = "timeData" + numDaysSinceUTC();
```

Then  I feed it into the local storage

```
chrome.storage.local.set({newStorageName : 0}, function(){});
```

Then when I check the contents of local storage rather than getting something corresponding to the format, I get literally "newStorageName" as the content(key), the variable name not the value of it. Which ends up overwriting. What is wrong?

Comment: And this is a browser extension right, it's not a website.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your object separately.  You cannot create dynamic property names with object literal syntax.  Instead, first create the object, then add the property using square bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[newStorageName] = 0;
chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function(){});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = numDaysSinceUTC();
localStorage.setItem("KeyName",data);
```